# PYTHON: Strange error at the END of 'for' loop through dataframe

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

I'm writing a script that mines baseball statistics from a website and inputs them into SQLite database. This piece of code is where I'm dumping from one of my dataframes (hit_stats) into the largest of my tables in the DB (Hitting Stats):

```
d = 0
for row in hit_stats:
    curs.execute('INSERT INTO Hitting_Stats (player_id, season_h, games_h, plate_appearances, at_bats,
runs, hits, doubles, triples, homeruns, total_bases, runs_batted_in, stolen_bases, caught_stealing, 
sacrifice_hits, sacrifice_flies, walks, hits_by_pitch, strikeouts_h, grounded_into_double_plays, 
batting_average, slugging_percentage, on_base_percentage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,
 ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (temp_player_id, hit_stats['Year'][d], hit_stats['G'][d],
hit_stats['PA'][d], hit_stats['AB'][d], hit_stats['R'][d], hit_stats['H'][d], hit_stats['2B'][d],
hit_stats['3B'][d], hit_stats['HR'][d], hit_stats['TB'][d], hit_stats['RBI'][d], hit_stats['SB'][d],
hit_stats['CS'][d], hit_stats['SH'][d], hit_stats['SF'][d], hit_stats['BB'][d], hit_stats['HP'][d],
hit_stats['SO'][d], hit_stats['GDP'][d], hit_stats['AVG'][d], hit_stats['SLG'][d], hit_stats['OBP'][d]))
    d += 1
```

(The indentations are correct in my actual code)

When I run the script, it says: "KeyError: 3"

Strangely, when I open up a Jupyter Notebook and run the following smaller bit of code, I get the correct output all the way through the single row/Series, but then I get the KeyError at the end AFTER the output:

```
d = 0
for row in hit_stats:
    print(hit_stats['Year'][d]) 
    d += 1
```

So it seems to be fine with everything until the end of the loop. Any ideas?

In case it isn't obvious, I'm a beginner, so if there's simply a better way to do this, feel free to just send me to a resource. Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Does your dataframe have the same layout as your target sqlite table? If so you could just worry about getting the format of your dataframe as you'd like it and then use the `pandas.Dataframe.to_sql` to insert it to your table. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, Grizzle! But the target table is going to be much larger. The dataframe has all the stats for a single player, with each row for one season, but the target table will have all the stats for EVERY player at that 'per season' granularity. I'm doing this by looping through a list of webpages, where each page has a single player table, grabbing that table, adding to the DB, and then moving on to the next player.

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against the wall for a while, I realized that for loops iterate through columns of dataframes by default, not rows. I re-wrote the loop using .iterrows and it worked.